# Echo string from highest to lowest similarity

Tags: php, foreach

Hard to explain, but I need some help. 
So I have, say 4 strings
`$query = 'google awesome';`,
`$result1 = 'google is cool';`,
`$result1 = 'google is awesome';`, and
`$result3 = 'other page';`.

Lets say I used PHP's `similar_text();`, and `$result1` is 60% similar, `$result2` is 70% similar and `$result3` is 5% similar.

How do I echo them in order from highest to lowest. Note that I am using more that 3 strings, I just echo the results using `foreach();`.

EDIT: HERE is my piece of code.

```
if(isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $results = file(__DIR__ . '/data/urls.txt');
    $query = $_GET['q'];
    foreach($results as $result) {
        $explode = explode('::', $result);
        $site = $explode[0];
        $title = $explode[1];
        /* if $query = similar to $title, echo ordered by similarity. */
    }
}
```

Comment: "Highest to lowest similarity" **with which string as a reference point?**

Comment: To the variable  `$query`.

Comment: Updated the code, I know it doesn't look good, but I can't use a database, haha.

Comment: By the way, the contents of a file are `http://url.com/::Title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For exampe you could build an array, with the results and the text, than sort the array and print.

```
 if(isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $results = explode("\n",file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/data/urls.txt')); // i assume all url is in a new line
    $query = $_GET['q'];
    $similarity = array();
    $map = array();        
    foreach($results as $result) {
        list($site,$title) = explode('::', $result);
        $similarity[$site] = similar_text($title,$query); //calculate similari by title for sites 0 is similar bigger is not realy similar
        $map[$site] = $title;            
    }
    asort($similarity,SORT_NUMERIC); //sort the results

    $limit = 10;
    foreach($similarity as $site=>$sim){
         print "<a href='{$site}'>{$map[$site]}</a>({$sim} % differnece what you need)<br/>";
         if( --$limit < 1) break;
    }
}
```

Links that should be read:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

Comment: I am highly confused. About to update my question, please read it again.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work. `https://v1k.org/search/?q=vlad1k` I have a couple of results added with my name.

Comment: https://v1k.org/search/?q=a still nothing. My URL file - https://v1k.org/search/data/urls.txt

Comment: It works good, but it shows the most revlevant searches last. How do you reverse that? https://v1k.org/search/?q=iPaint

Comment: Alright, great thanks a lot. One last question: how do I limit the results to 10? No pages just results.

Comment: updated. decrese a variable, thats initaial value is 10, and if this is less than 0 breaks the loop.

Comment: Making my own google - https://v1k.org/search/ lol haha finishing up a couple of things and its ready.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you store all strings in an array and use a user defined comparison function such as [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: I'd further precompute `similar_text` to avoid recomputing it unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has the `usort` function to create your own comparison function. Straight from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
<?php
$ref = "some ref string";

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    global $ref;
    return similar_text($ref, $a) - similar_text($ref, $b);
}

$a = array("one", "two", "three");

usort($a, "cmp");

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
?>
```

Note that this might be quite inefficient, as you are calculating `similar_text` more than once per string.

Comment: +1 for basically the correct answer, BUT for a proper sort you _do_ want the `-1` (or any negative) return though, otherwise it assumes some are equal which are not. `return similar_text($ref, $a) - similar_text($ref, $b);` would be a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will allow for $results with the same similarity ranking to not overwrite each other. They are listed first come first serve at that point.

```
$query = 'google awesome';
$results = array('google is cool', 'google is awesome','other page');
foreach ($results as $result) {
  $rank = similar_text($query,$result);
  $rankings[$rank][] = $result;
}
krsort($rankings);
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without an array?

Comment: is there any reason you can't use an array?

Comment: It seems to be a little harder for me. idk why.

Comment: well i suggest you learn how to use arrays then, they are pretty convenient for doing things! you *could* do this without an array but it would involve lots of loops and conditions and much more code.

Comment: i mean all you have to do to get the rankings in the order you want is just copy/paste this code..what were you wanting to do after that, just echo out the results or something?

Comment: Oh I know arrays, I'm just not a fan of them.